# QLayout in Quasar

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

May I know what's the different if we choose capital vs small letter in the above four highlighted position in QLayout?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> **Using UpperCase**

using Capital "H" and "F" (uppercase character instead of lowercase) will make your Header and Footer to a fixed position. It Means it will not scroll with window it will remain at fixed position. like header will Fixed in top position and footer will fixed bottom position.

> **For Capital L and R**

using Capital character “L”  will make your layout left side (drawer) be in a fixed position. Same applies for “R” (right side / drawer).

> **Using LowerCase**

With lower character "h" and "f" makes header and footer as it is by default position.

Hope It will clear your doubt.

Comment: Thanks, what about l/L and r/R?

Comment: @william007 can you please see my updated answer as I have updated as per your comment.